# Rails Form_For Select With Dual Purpose

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, form-for, html-select

I have form for adding a new job.  On my form I have a select drop-down list.  I need to associate the new job to a customer.  The following works great.

```
<%= f.collection_select :customer_id, Customer.all, :id, :business_name %>
```

But, what if I want to also be able to send in a customer_id to the new form?  Can I have the form's select drop-down show all the possible customers, as above, but have it auto select the customer_id I pass into the form, if a customer_id is passed in?

url = ...jobs/new

OR

url = ...jobs/new?customer_id=5

I apologize if I did not explain this well enough.
Thanks in advance.
--jc

Answer (score 0):

I think you do what you're trying to achieve this by populating the customer_id field on the job you're creating in your controller if customer_id is present in the request params.  This should make that particular customer be the initially selected option in the form.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select

e.g. Something like.

```
if params[:customer_id].present?
    job.customer_id = params[:customer_id]
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  This worked for me after "finally" finding a similar question in this site.  Sorry for not seeing this sooner.

Answer (score 0):

If you declaring the instance variable `@customer` in your controller action then you can use selected option as:

```
<%= f.collection_select :customer_id, Customer.all, :id, :business_name, {:selected => @customer.id} %>
```

Comment: <%= f.collection_select :customer_id, Customer.all, :id, :business_name, {:selected => !params[:customer_id].nil? ? params[:customer_id] : '' } %>